# C how to iterate and add a new node after a desired node in single Linked List

Tags: c, list, pass-by-reference, singly-linked-list, function-definition

```c
typedef struct ITEM {
  int value;
  struct ITEM *next;
}ITEM;

int add_after(ITEM *list, ITEM *c_item, int value)
{  
    ITEM *elem;

    //if head is NULL, it is an empty list
    if(c_item == NULL || list == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    //create a new node 
    elem = malloc(sizeof(ITEM));
    if(elem == NULL)
    {
      return -1;
    }
    elem->value = value;

    // iteration
    while(list != NULL)
    {
       if(list == c_item)
        {
          elem->next = list->next;
          c_item->next = elem;
          return 1;
        }
          list = list->value;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What it should do:
`c_item` should be equal to one of the exiting nodes in the `list`. After finding an equal, it should make a new node `elem` and put that node infront of `c_item`.

What my code does:
`list` is HEAD value and compared with the `c_item` value and if its not the same then `list` goes to the next `value` in the list. After finding the equal, then it adds `elem` node to the list infront.

Problem:
This only works with 1 existing node in the `list`. If there is 2 nodes then it gets stuck at `list = list->value;`.

```c
// Linked List 10->20->30->NULL

//Input:
c_item = 20
elem = 100

//Output:
10->20->100->30->NULL
```

Comment: c_item is not a node. So it is unclear whether you need to pass to the function a value that can be present in a node in the list or a pointer to a node.

Comment: @ If you already have a pointer to a node in the linked list ITEM *c_item then just write c_item->next = elem. The pointer to the head node is just redundant,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have the basics of most of what you want to do in place. Let's try to to reorganize your pieces, and perhaps you can get close to your desired solution.

I would first use comments to describe what I want to accomplish in the function.

```
int add_after (ITEM *list, ITEM *c_item, int value) {

    // Check c_item and list are not NULL
    // Check if c_item is in list
    // Create new elem with value
    // Add new elem after c_item

}
```

Then, I would write the code that accomplishes each of these things.

- *Check `c_item` and `list` are not `NULL`*

```
    if (! (c_item && list)) return -1;
```

- *Check if `c_item` is in `list`*

```
    if (! list_has_item(list, c_item)) return -1;
```

- *Create new `elem` with `value`*

```
    ITEM *elem = create_item(value);
    if (elem == NULL) return -1;
```

- *Add new `elem` after `c_item`*

```
    ITEM *old_after = c_item->next;
    c_item->next = elem;
    elem->next = old_after;
```

This last bit actually the specific question you ask about. The implementation remembers what used to be after the the `c_item`, makes the new element to be after it instead, then puts what used to be after `c_item` after the new element.

It is possible to make the same thing happen without the temporary. It is debatable what is more clear, but if you are curious, feel free to try to rewrite the three lines of above into two lines instead.

I think you already understand how to check if an item is in the list and how to create a new item, so I will leave those up to you to implement.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply but I just noticed that `list = list->value;` is not a good code to iterate through the list since it's basically pointer = int which is wrong conversion.  `list = list->next;` would give me a `NULL` . How do you iterate to the list of  without getting errors?

Comment: If the code `for(;list && (list != c_item);list = list->next) {} return list;` returns 0, then `c_item` is not in `list`.